# How to get R contour function to plot decimals

Tags: r

I am trying to plot the contours of a function made of two gaussians, one centered at (2, 2) and the other centered at (-2, -2). Here is my code.

```
k1 <- 2
k2 <- 2
mu1 <- rbind(2, 2)
mu2 <- rbind(-2, -2)
sigma1 <- rbind(c(.6, 0), c(0, .6))
sigma2 <- rbind(c(.3, 0), c(0, .3))
det1 <- det(sigma1)
det2 <- det(sigma2)
inv1 <- solve(sigma1)
inv2 <- solve(sigma2)
x <- runif(1000, -5, 5)
y <- runif(1000, -5, 5)
w <- rbind(x, y)
ratio <- function(v){
  quotient <- log((2*pi)^(-k1/2)*det1^(-1/2)*(exp((-1/2)*t(v-mu1)%*%inv1%*%(v-mu1))))/log((2*pi)^(-k2/2)*det2^(-1/2)*(exp((-1/2)*t(v-mu2)%*%inv2%*%(v-mu2))))
  return(quotient)
}

z <- apply(w, 2, ratio)
round.z <- round(z, digits=0)
df <- cbind(x, y, z, round.z)
df <- as.data.frame(df)

grid <- with(df, interp(x, y, z))
contour(grid, levels=0:10, asp=1)
```

But when I plot these contours I just get the contours with whole number values. It looks like this:
[image]

There should be more, similar-looking contours in the first quadrants that have decimal values (because I am taking a ratio) but they do not appear. I can't seem to find how to get contour() to plot decimals. Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: The `levels` argument specifies the contour levels.  Use `levels=c((0:10)/10, 2:10)` to get 0.1, 0.2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As user2554330 commented, I can use levels=c((0:10)/10, 2:10). Thank you to them!